# Google Cloud BigQuery API c++ session create error

Tags: c++, google-bigquery

I have an error when I try to create a session with BigQuery.

I try to connect to BigQuery db using google api. What I had done:

```
 auto options = google::cloud::Options {}.set<google::cloud::UnifiedCredentialsOption>(
                google::cloud::MakeServiceAccountCredentials(keyfile_));
            
            options.set<google::cloud::EndpointOption>("bigquery.googleapis.com");
            auto connection = google::cloud::bigquery_storage_v1::MakeBigQueryReadConnection(options);
            bq_client_ = std::make_unique<google::cloud::bigquery_storage_v1::BigQueryReadClient>(connection);
            read_session_.set_table(table_name_);
            read_session_.set_data_format(google::cloud::bigquery::storage::v1::DataFormat::AVRO);
            bq_session_ = bq_client_->CreateReadSession(project_id_, read_session_, kMaxReadStreams_);
```

And my StatusOr pointer bq_session returns an errorcode 'kUnavailable(14) Error in non-idempotent operation. CreateReadSession: Empty address list'

Google and ChatGPT couldn't help to resolve this.

upd:
Solve this specifying environment variable for gRPC and requires key .pem file